# How to share a :memory: database between different process in python using python sqlite3 package

Tags: python, sqlite, memory, share, apsw

scenario is shown as below,i got many processes to do CPU-bound work and read only on the same database,i know cache and uri key words could be used for sqlite to share database cache between threads,but how about between processes?it's better to be available both for linux and windows, Thank you!

```
def run(self):
    self.phyconn = apsw.Connection(self.fileName)
    self.memconn = apsw.Connection(":memory:")
    try:#backup.__exit__() just make sure copy if finished,not close backup,so with is good,memconn is still exist when out
        with self.memconn.backup("main", self.phyconn, "main") as backup:
            # call with 0 to get the total pages
            backup.step(0)
            total = backup.pagecount

            stepped = 0
            one_percent = total if total < 100 else total // 100
            last_percentage = 0
            while stepped <= total:
                if self.cancel:
                    #self.progressCanceled.emit()
                    self.memconn=None
                    return
                backup.step(one_percent)
                stepped = stepped + one_percent
                stepped_percentage = stepped*100//total
                if stepped_percentage != last_percentage:
                    last_percentage = stepped_percentage
                    #self.progressChanged.emit(stepped_percentage)
                    websocket.UpdateLoadDBProgress(stepped_percentage,self.sid)
```

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve? Why can't you use the DB file?

Comment: get many processes read DB at the same  time but not write,so i think if it could just be loaded to memory and let every process share it for io efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.
The whole point if processes is to isolate their memory from each other.
(Most OSes allow shared memory, but there is no portable mechanism for that.)

Even if it were possible, it would not be any faster, because both SQLite and the OS cache the data.

Comment: even if sqlite cache the data,is not that per connection?and OS dose not know if you just read,so must get one copy per connection when process is different.
after searching , it seems to mmap with vfs is the only wayt,but don't see any lib implement that on sqlite

Comment: SQLite's per-connection cache is 2 MB by default. The OS certainly knows what accesses you have done.